# Передача аргумента в метод

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть следующая конструкция:

```
var FormLogs = (function(f){

    var FormLogs = (function()
    {
        function FormLogs()
        {
            this.fieldName = null;
        }

        return FormLogs;
    })();

    FormLogs.prototype.init = function(fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.test();
    };

    FormLogs.prototype.test = function(){
        console.log(this.fieldName)
    };

    return new FormLogs;

})(FormLogs);

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     FormLogs.init(["1","2","3"]);
});
```

Результат в консоли (на скрине):
http://s017.radikal.ru/i411/1503/59/27bfc90f480c.jpg

Уточните, пожалуйста, почему или откуда берется **prototype**, если я передаю в метод только значение?

P.S. А если мы передадим в метод обычную строку

```
FormLogs.init("строка");
```

то результат будет ожидаемый.

```
--- строка
```

P.S.S. Почему-то при передаче объектов/массивов берется этот `__proto__`.

Comment: @DVirt, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Ну так массив - это объект. У любого объекта есть родитель, через _proto_ видны свойства/методы родителя. Подробнее смотрите [здесь](http://learn.javascript.ru/prototype)